# Ignorar qualquer espaço em branco no meio de uma string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

estou tentando criar uma regex que seja capaz de encontrar em um texto uma string mesmo que exista algum espaço em branco no meio das palavras. Por exemplo, procuro no texto pelos seguintes trechos

"conciliação prejudicada" ou ainda "inconciliados"

Mas como nem tudo é sempre lindo pode existir algum espaço perdido no meio das palavras, por exemplo:

"con ciliação prejud icada" ou "i n  c on ciliados"

Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
padrao = re.search(r'i\s*n\s*c\s*o\s*n\s*c\s*i\s*l\s*i\s*a\s*d\s*o\s*s|'
                     r'c\s*o\s*n\s*c\s*i\s*l\s*i\s*a\s*ç\s*ã\s*o\s*(p\s*r\s*e\s*j\s*u\s*d\s*i\s*c\s*a\s*d\s*a|r\s*e\s*j\s*e\s*i\s*t\s*a\s*d\s*a)', text)
```

Minha pergunta é.. existe um modo menos feio e gigantesco de ignorar esses espaços?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ou você pode remover qualquer espaço primeiro e realizar a busca depois:

```
texto = re.sub("\s", "", texto)
```

Você poderá, então, buscar o texto normalmente utilizando sua expressão regular. Dependendo dos seus objetivos, talvez você queira colocar tudo em grupos de captura:

```
resultado = re.search("(conciliação)(prejudicada)|(inconciliados)", texto)
```

E se quiser todos os resultados, poderá utilizar o `re.findall`:

```
resultados = re.findall("(conciliação)(prejudicada)|(inconciliados)", texto)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! resolveu um problemão da maneira mais simples.

Answer (score 0):

Um jeito menos feio é de deixar uma função gerar o regex pra você:

```
def to_regex(s):
    return '\s*'.join(s)

print(to_regex('teste'))
```